# Invocation of @CacheEvict annotation

Tags: spring, spring-cache

I know that @CacheEvict performs a cleanup operation on the cached data in Spring.I just wanted understand ::

If I annotate a Method with `@CacheEvict` will it be invoked automatically just like `@PreDestroy` annotation of JSF.i.e at the time of bean object is being garbage collected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@CacheEvict` is not like `@PreDestroy`; it is not invoked automatically.

As the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-evict) describes, `@CacheEvict` is evaluated anytime an `@CacheEvict` annotated bean method is invoked.  You can conditionally control when the eviction actually occurs, along with whether the eviction occurs before the method executes or after (the default), using the `@CacheEviction` annotation, [`beforeInvocation` attribute](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html#beforeInvocation--), along with controlling other settings.

Spring's declarative configuration for `@CacheEvict` is also not tied to JVM garbage collection.  Usually, you need to rely on the capabilities of the individual caching providers (e.g. ehcache, memcached), or more advanced providers such as (e.g. Apache Geode, Hazelcast or Redis) to configure, tune and control eviction triggers and actions at the JVM level.

Each provider may have similar and also different capabilities in this regard.

Hope this helps.